# Convert sed regex to vim regex

Tags: regular-expression

I got this sed regex I found:

```
sed '/start/!d;s//&\n/;s/.*\n//;:a;/end/bb;$!{n;ba};:b;s//\n&/;P;D'
```

which basically outputs the content that is between a starting point and an end point.

```
##1##
this is a test
with multiple
line
##z##
```

and replacing `start` with `##1##`, and `end` to `##z##` would give:

```
this is a test
with multiple
line
```

If there are multiple occurrences of the `##1##` and `##z##`, then it would obviously show all the in-between text of said occurrence, like so:

```
##1##
this is a test
with multiple
line
##z##
##1##
this is a test
with multiple
line
##z##
```

to

```
this is a test
with multiple
line


this is a test
with multiple
line
```

To clarify even more:

```
##1##
this is a test
with multiple
line
##z##
##2##
test
##z##
```

would obviously give only what is specified as starting point (since the ending point `##z##` is always the same).
So if i use `##2##` instead as starting point:

```
test
```

This would give the above as output.

My goal is to convert this to a compatible regex for vim.
I'm using [this site](http://www.vimregex.com/) and the local manual as help but, I'm unsure where to start for converting the above to vim regex.

Comment: Wow, that sed is spooky :) What should happen if there are multiple occurrences of `##1##` and `##z##`? Please use a more complete example.

Comment: Just added more example.

Comment: Thank you! I guess any lines not between `##1##` and `##z##` should not be in the output, correct?

Comment: Yes! Exactly on point.

Comment: added a last example to illustrate a different case :)

Comment: That’s a sed program, not a regex /pedant. Converting it to a vim program could certainly be done naïvely, but there may be a more idiomatic translation. Do you have a preference? Also, can you share where you found the ses program (if you didn’t create it wholesale)?

Comment: I said that i found it, but i can't exactly recall how it was made, as i found a part of it, and made the rest myself. I'm also aware it can't be 1:1 conversion as vim and sed have different regex engine/syntax, but that's also why I'm asking :). I don't really have a preference, as i just managed to do this particular task in sed, and preferred to do it in pure vimscript instead (as in, vim regex). @D.BenKnoble

Comment: Do you want the result to be left in the buffer in the end? (Effectively deleting everything except for the matched blocks?) Do you care very specifically about the number of blank lines between and around the blocks? (Please [edit] the question to update your more exact specifications.)

Comment: Also consider whether this is potentially an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What is it that you're *actually* trying to accomplish? What's the context for this text operation? If you share more, you might find more direct or more useful solutions to the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Well, to answer your first comment: if you run the sed command on the example text i showed, you'll see that it does literally what i mentioned (which is showing the in-between text, of a starting and ending point, nothing else), though, it does add a newline before and after, as the example showed (can't remember why i added this back then).

Comment: As for the second comment, the goal is literally the same as the question, afaik. Though i could open another post called "how to show in-between text in vimscript" or something along those lines, but i was more curious on how to port an existing, similar solution (since they are related to regex) to vim regex. :) (hopefully that answer your questions) @filbranden

Comment: I guess the problem is that sed and Vim work differently (at a conceptual level) since one is a filter (takes text in input, prints filtered/modified text in output), while Vim is a text editor (opens a file into a buffer, executes a series of modifications into that buffer, writes that buffer back to a file.) Yes, you could consider the written buffer as analogous to the filtered output of sed. But there are other options, for instance you could store the result into a Vim register instead...

Comment: I'm well aware! that's why i asked initially. Vim regex and sed have similarities, but i never said they were the same (which is why i have to port it). And i did explain in details what the sed script does, though i guess i could dissect it a bit more instead of it's effect...

Comment: I did thought of just putting the result in a Vim register (which is what i have been doing too) but i was curious about making it in vimscript so, yeah.

Comment: I don't get the problem. At it's core, Vim and sed use basic regular expressions (BRE), which are compatible (with several extensions by Vim). So you should be able to use the sed regular expressions. Now what you are posting, is a solution of sed to make it multi-line aware, that's why you need to append to the pattern space before you can replace the `\n`. This is not needed in Vim, since it supports several ways to manipulate the multi-line buffer. So what exactly do you want to do in Vim?

Comment: I tried running the same exact sed expression on my post, directly in vim, but to no avail, which is also why i posted initially :D. @ChristianBrabandt

Comment: No, don't need those newlines :). Was there by accident when i made it a while ago, don't remember why i did it, but i don't need that behavior. @Quasímodo

Comment: @NordineLotfi well of course Vim does not understand the various sed command (at least not all of it). That's why I am asking what you are trying to achieve. But I don't think it's a regular expression problem here.

Comment: I briefly explained in my post (and some comment) that the goal was basically to show the in-between text, between a starting point and an ending point. :) (which is what the sed script is doing). @ChristianBrabandt

Comment: @NordineLotfi use the `:g` command for that

Comment: @NordineLotfi and no, that is not what the sed script is doing. If you just want to print text between two patterns, the sed script can be a whole lot simplified. What your sed script is actually doing is appending a lot of thing to the pattern space in order to replace line breaks, which by default sed won't do because it works linewise

Comment: yeah, that's what i ended doing. D.BenKnoble's solution worked for what i wanted, but since i also wanted to select the match, i just did `:g/^##1##\n.*/+,/##z##/-` @ChristianBrabandt

Comment: I see @ChristianBrabandt it's been a while so i didn't remember what it did in detail :D, guess i should refresh my sed knowledge one of these days...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extremely simple function which does the job far more idiomatically:

```
function! Between(start, end) abort
  let [start_line, _] = searchpairpos(a:start, '', a:end, 'bWn')
  let [end_line, _] = searchpairpos(a:start, '', a:end, 'Wn')
  if start_line is# 0 || end_line is# 0
    return
  endif
  call setline(start_line, '') " or: execute start_line 'delete'
  call setline(end_line, '') " or: execute end_line 'delete'
endfunction
```

Name it whatever you want, and then do, e.g.,

```
call Between('##1##', '##z##')
```

(which you could bind to a key, perhaps).

To work on the whole file, you *might* be able to use `:global` (or even just `:%call Between(...)`), or you may need a loop wrapping this function and traversing the file. In the case of the latter, I would use `search(a:start)` to find the next start and then `+` to be inside the nested region; then I would call the function. This is faster than calling the function on every line.

Comment: I noticed this works only when i visually select or place the cursor in the in-between text, and then run `call Between('##1##', '##z##')`. Would be great if it does it without needing to place the cursor.

Comment: @NordineLotfi you could always add `execute '/' escape(a:start, '/') '/+'` or similar to the beginning of the function; that would position the cursor.

Answer (score 3):

```
:g/END\|\%^/,/START\|\%$/s/.*//
```

This global command marks all lines matching `END` or the beginning of file (`\%^`). Then it proceeds to delete everything from the marked lines up to `START` or the end of file (`\%$`) by using the substitution command `s/.*//`.

A side-by-side example:

```
Before           |After
________________________________
test             |
START            |
this is a test   |this is a test
with multiple    |with multiple
line             |line
END              |
0                |
START            |
0101             |0101
END              |
11               |
111              |
```

If you don't want the blank lines, you can replace `s/.*//` by `d` in the global command.

Comment: Hm, I didnt even consider the lines between delimiters. Whoops.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yeah, but the example didn't have any either, so I think your solution is also acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, remember you can always do

```
:%!sed '/start/\!d;s//&\n/;s/.*\n//;:a;/end/bb;$\!{n;ba};:b;s//\n&/;P;D'
```

And that’s still “vim” :P

Comment: Just tried this on Vim 8.1, show `E34: No previous command`

Comment: I think Vim tries to do something with the exclamation marks, so they need to be escaped.

Comment: @Quasímodo is right; vim will substitute bangs for previous commands for you